# Having Footer Problems (overlapping content, width issues).  Can you help me?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to make an our team page using bootstrap but I can't get the footer to act right.  At first it was not filling the width of the page, now (I'm not so sure what I did) this problem is solved but it is overlapping onto the content: some thumnails, writing, and a link.  The page with the problem is: http://rdtaxsavers.com/new/OurTeam.php

My css file is at rdtaxsavers.com/new/css/bootstrap.css

You'll notice that the rdtaxsavers.com site footer works fine.  Thanks in advance!

EDIT: I got it back to where the footer is not overlapping but now the width issue is back.  You will see in my css that my modal-footer class has width:100%; at the end of it but this does not fix the issue.

EDIT: This is driving me nuts.  When I fix the width problem then it overlaps, when I fix the overlap the width is broken.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are placing the footer inside the Container class, the container class has a width of 1170px. therefore the footer will not be 100% width to the body. move the footer out of container class. or you have to change the width of container class.

this is what you have:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">...</div>
    <footer>...</footer>
</div>
```

try to do this:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">...</div>
</div>
<footer>...</footer>
```

Comment: Thats what I was thinking.  There are a bunch of </div> before my footer so wouldn't that mean it is not in the container though?

Comment: I added a div and it fixed the width problem, by taking the footer out of the div, but now the footer is riding too high and overlapping content.  Sorry for the questions but I don't really know html or css that well/at all.  I appreciate your help so far.

Answer (score 1):

Try clearing the float:left in the ul.thumbnails element.

Comment: Thanks for responding so fast, how would I do that?